What are the essential formulas to understand for AP Physics 1?
I am looking for the essential formulas for AP Physics 1 to memorize to be successful in that course.  I have a teacher that does not give us resources to solve problems and he is not very good at lessons either.

If I may offer a bit of a frame challenge, physics is not about memorizing formulae.  It can be helpful, but the key content they are trying to teach you in AP physics is not a collection of formulae, but rather how to think about physics.  Which formulae one finds the need to memorize is really a personal decision.  Myself, I tended to intuit a great deal about the physics itself, and reason through the problems instead of memorizing formulae.  Accordingly, the "essential" formulae for me was quite a small set.  For others, it may be larger, simply because they approached it differently.

At least when I took it, the AP Physics test had an official formula sheet that you would be given in the exam. Those are the most important formulas to know. But, physics is much more about knowing how to apply those formulas, than having them memorized (which is why they give you the sheet :))

On the big exam in the spring, you will be asked to give an English description for the solution of many of the problems.  When I taught AP Physics 1, I didn't like that approach because English is often ambiguous, but that approach will lessen the need for you to memorize equations.  Of course, that approach will increase the need for you to understand the underlying concepts.

AP physics 1 is large enough that it will be hard to find one de-facto list of equations.  And, of course, it is worth addressing the elephant in the room that physics is not just about plugging values into formulae.  It's about how you think about the problem.
As an alternative, I'd suggest taking a look at the AP Physics 1 Cirriculum, and constructing your own formulae lists for each topic.  I believe the act of researching your own formulae list may indeed help prepare you for the test.  If you can identify what is important on your own, that suggests you understand the topics at hand!
And, while stack exchange probably can't help with questions in the form "is equation XYZ important?" if you have any questions about how such equations get used, those can likely be phrased in a way that can be answered on stack exchange, and we can help you with them.
